# Redirect to action causing 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string Name, int number)
    {
        Stored stored = new Stored();
        var isValid = from c in _db.stored
                      where (c.Name == Name && c.Id == number)
                      select c;


        if (isValid.Count() > 0)
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
        else if (isValid.Count() > 0 && c.hasExpired)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Send", "Mail", new { theNumber = number });
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

Target class

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Send(int number)
```

Both have the HTTP Post attribute

Comment: Can you provide us with more details? Maybe logs?

Comment: All i get is a 404 for the following url http://localhost:64765/Mail/Send?theNumber=2  Controller is called MailController

Comment: Have you tried using debugger?

Comment: yes, theNumber is correct in the debugger

Comment: Can you post the logs for the exception?

Comment: Exception: System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'Send' was not found on controller

Comment: Please can you update the question with code of the controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128239/discussion-between-sid-and-user2620804).

Comment: You cannot navigate to a POST method. You need a GET method for `Send()` (remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute)

Answer (score 2):

Using [HttpGet] solved the issue

Answer (score -2):

check from Controller Name;
and you need to use [HTTPPOST] befor the function.
example :

```html
[HTTPPOST]
public ActionResult Send(int number)
{
  return RedirectToAction("Send", "Mail", new { theNumber = number });
}
```

Comment: yep, this is the same as what i have

Comment: This will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: soory,[HTTPPOST]
public ActionResult Send(int number)
{
  return RedirectToAction("Send", "Mail", new { theNumber = number });
}

Comment: sir , you want to redirect to from send to send ?

Comment: this is error
you can send a value from Send to another page just

Comment: open this picture.